# how can I solve this makefile error?

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, makefile

When I install   a software  and  I do ./configure  && make  , it happend

```
  /usr/bin/ld: 找不到 -lfontconfig
  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What's  *-lfontconfig* means? How can i solve  it ?
make-file:

[image]

Comment: You are missing the `fontconfig` library.

Comment: how can install fontconfig library?,I don't find the  way to  install this on internet @merlin2011

Comment: [This](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=fontconfig) was the first result for Ubuntu fontconfig.

Comment: I find  that  I have install the fontconfig library,but problem still be same, I don't  know   reason@merlin2011

Comment: If you want more specific help, you must provide enough information to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I know problem's reason it 's that I have installed  fontconfig library, but 'g++  -lfontconfig --verbose  '  can't  find where  fontconfig   is

Comment: Then specify its location via the `-L` option in `LDFLAGS`.